# Logging to Amazon Developer web page using casperjs/phantomjs

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a problem trying to log in to amazon developer web page with CasperJS - email and pass are successfully entered, but on a 'sign in' button click, I receive a message to enter an email that is valid (and my email is valid - I successfully log in manually). Tried to log in to Facebook and it worked with pretty much the same code.
I used code from this website  : http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-login-to-amazon-using-casperjs-working-example/

Thanks!

Comment: It's helpful if you add the exact code you used to the question (rather than a tutorial link), and any other things you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> U need 2 use `--cookies-file` option, b/c of a bug, and try twice.

```
./casperjs --cookies-file=./MyFile amazon.js >/dev/stdout
```

Here's my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391254/not-able-to-get-phantomjs-example-to-work/41396226#41396226)

Comment: You have no idea how much time I spent testing this. It finally works!!! Thank you sooo much. God bless you :)

Comment: I'm glad to help you!

Comment: You can mark this answer as a solution to let the people know - that's working!

Comment: Another related issue: [How to add an application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561846/how-to-call-a-buttons-onclick-method-in-phantomjs/41578605#41578605) there, by using PhantomJS

Comment: You can run [that script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561846/how-to-call-a-buttons-onclick-method-in-phantomjs/41578605#41578605) like so:
`./phantomjs --cookies-file=./cookies.txt amazon_add_app.js mail pass app_name >/dev/stdout`