# Not able to get PhantomJS example to work

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to write a PhantomJS script that will automate Android app submission to the Amazon App Store.  I am basing my script on this example: http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-login-amazon-using-phantomjs-working-example/.  I have modified that example to work with https://developer.amazon.com/home.html instead of the URL used in the example.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var steps=[];
var testindex = 0;
var loadInProgress = false;//This is set to true when a page is still loading

/*********SETTINGS*********************/
var username = 'unknown';
var password = 'unknown';

var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = false;//Script is much faster with this field set to false
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;
/*********SETTINGS END*****************/


/* Get command line args user password*/
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

if (args.length === 1) {
  console.log('Try to pass some arguments when invoking this script!');
} else {
  args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
    console.log(i + ': ' + arg);
    if ( i === 1 ) { username = arg; }
    if ( i === 2 ) { password = arg; }
  });
}

if ( username == 'unknown' ) {
        console.log('Please specify username and password');
        phantom.exit();
}
if ( password == 'unknown' ) {
        console.log('Please specify username and password');
        phantom.exit();
}


console.log('All settings loaded, start with execution');
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
/**********DEFINE STEPS THAT FANTOM SHOULD DO***********************/
steps = [

        /*
         * Step 1 - Open Amazon home page
         */
        function(){
                console.log('Step 1 - Open Amazon home page');
                page.open("https://developer.amazon.com/home.html", function(status) {
                        console.log('status is '+ status );
                });
        },

                /*
     * Step 2 - Populate and submit the login form
     */
    function(username,password){
            console.log('Step 2 - Populate and submit the login form');
            // var appActionToken = page.evaluate(function() { return $('input[name="appActionToken"]').attr('value'); });
            // console.log( 'appActionToken is ' + appActionToken );
            console.log( 'username is ' + username );
            page.evaluate(function(username,password){
                    console.log( '  username is ' + username );
                    document.getElementById("ap_email").value=username;
                    document.getElementById("ap_password").value=password;
                    document.getElementById("ap_signin_form").submit();
            },username, password);
    },


        /*
         * Step 3 - Wait Amazon to login user. After user is successfully logged in,
         * user is redirected to home page. Content of the home page is saved to AmazonLoggedIn.html.
         * You can find this file where phantomjs.exe file is. You can open this file using Chrome to ensure that you are logged in.
         */
        function(){
                console.log("Step 3 - blah blah blah");
                var fs = require('fs');
                var result = page.evaluate(function() {
                        return document.querySelectorAll("html")[0].outerHTML;
                });
                fs.write('AmazonLoggedIn.html',result,'w');
        },
];

/**********END STEPS THAT FANTOM SHOULD DO***********************/

//Execute steps one by one
interval = setInterval(executeRequestsStepByStep,50);

function executeRequestsStepByStep(){
    if (loadInProgress == false && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
        console.log("testindex is " + testindex );
        if ( testindex == 1 ) {
                console.log( "username is " + username );
            steps[testindex](username, password);
        } else {
            steps[testindex]();
        }
        testindex++;
    }
    if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
        console.log("test complete!");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}

/**
 * These listeners are very important in order to phantom work properly.
 * Using these listeners, we control loadInProgress marker which controls, weather a page is fully loaded.
 * Without this, we will get content of the page, even a page is not fully loaded.
 */
page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log('Loading started');
};
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log('Loading finished');
};
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

When I run the script output does get written to the AmazonLoggedIn.html file but the contents indicate that the login failed.  I am pretty certain that I am using the correct credentials.  Here is what the resulting AmazonLoggedIn.html looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like plain login is impossible, i have tried with phantom/casperjs and - doesn't work.
Only works with Cookie (and works perfectly).

```
/*********SETTINGS*********************/
var page = require('webpage').create({viewportSize:{width: 1600,height: 900},
settings:{userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
javascriptEnabled:'true',
loadImages:'false'
}}), fs = require('fs');
/*********SETTINGS END*****************/
console.log('All settings loaded, start with execution');

page.onLoadStarted = function() { console.log('Loading started') };
page.onLoadFinished =function() { console.log('Loading finished') };
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) { console.log(msg) };

// in these vars, you need to have the values of your cookies:

var at_main='Atza|IwEBIDds270mDqc9pBDWo49OWmIG2UAKXp8N3eYPzCuYn3fFGojBcZXag7M3uZdGurgA28cZA49zToQaoJ0DkQ8ZiAzu6EypTNzrskJNRp-IBqmKPh78s4oSU7o5oBv-7sgmjT-E8_pyxS0oC-t0SYAXdjSYzUeJbXUTTdweOVj_astxNj6_H1uqWysZw59G6sYkwq3A5JhCN_NVZszHUpmQvU4JrhAzV5a8vZgAJmFG5lnK8xl3Nk3uZNTVG3pQYhQ_SLPirg9cdDWICCQFO-fljcnad4PoPRQqdPsUw6OpCHrXEmkEDhn0EC49RzSA63bFlUKTAUUfREuiv0EXoobi19l4Ae98cq_qz38CA4UKF4OHWyBDpAZwZtgUANlaj_l82xUbWwR6yUgZByB-7jICsIs0',
sess_at_main='RDK4Kzj6ywmJnwhNdqkc37bjioL/FEX20dcHnjMMMUk=',
session_id='166-7700254-1158037',
ubid_main='157-9343046-5202510',
x_main='DBSZwuolSC12SSlS36cN7VhwXIg770zKumtGLK9THJji?XszMxT4xe?0FNT@MMfQ';

phantom.cookies = [{// an array of objects
  'name'     : 'at-main',   
  'value'    :  at_main,
  'domain'   : '.amazon.com',
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : false,
  'secure'   : true,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 43800) }, //5 years // end of 1 
{ 'name'     : 'sess-at-main',   
  'value'    :  sess_at_main,
  'domain'   : '.amazon.com',
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : false,
  'secure'   : true,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 43800) }, // end of 2
{ 'name'     : 'session-id',
  'value'    :  session_id,
  'domain'   : '.amazon.com',
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : false,
  'secure'   : true,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 43800) }, // end of 3
{ 'name'     : 'ubid-main',   
  'value'    :  ubid_main,
  'domain'   : '.amazon.com',
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : false,
  'secure'   : true,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 43800) }, // end of 4
{ 'name'     : 'x-main',
  'value'    :  x_main,
  'domain'   : '.amazon.com',
  'path'     : '/',
  'httponly' : false,
  'secure'   : true,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 43800) } // end of 5
]

//Execute steps one by one
page.open("https://developer.amazon.com/home.html", function(status){
console.log('Step 1');
                     page.render('step1.png');
                                             setTimeout(step2,3000);
function step2(){
console.log("Step 2");
                     page.render('step2.png');
                                            var result=page.evaluate(function(){return document.documentElement.outerHTML});
                                                                     fs.write('AmazonLoggedIn.html',result,'w'); phantom.exit();
}
});
```

[step1.png](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBndmUxZDdrQXZXbk0)

```
// in these vars, you need to have the values of your cookies:

var at_main=' ',
sess_at_main=' ',
session_id=' ',
ubid_main=' ',
x_main=' ';
```

[image]

You probably also need to set the `Keep me signed in` chekbox:
[image]

**Update:** 
To avoid that hell with the login, you can use `--cookies-file` option! 
After the second attempt, your script works like a charm !!

```
./phantomjs --cookies-file=./cookies_2.txt am.js luxadm1@gmail.com pass >/dev/stdout
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Igor. I hope I will have time today to try out your solution.  I assume that I need to get the values for at_main, sess_at_main, session_id, ubid_main and x_main from my browser, right?

Comment: Update: To avoid that hell with the login, you can use `--cookies-file` option! After the second attempt, your script works like a charm !!
`./phantomjs --cookies-file=./cookies_2.txt your_script.js email pass >/dev/stdout`

Comment: you can use your original script with the `--cookies-file` option, all will work, maybe after second attempt, but will !!

Comment: What is the easiest way to get the values for the cookies? Is there a programmatic way to get these values? Or do I just have to cut-n-paste out my browser and into the cookies-file?

Comment: The new cookie will be written into the `cookies-file` automatically by `PhantomJS`.

Comment: I just ran my script with your suggestions and it works! Thanks.

Comment: I can't get this to work. What do I put in the variables? Do I just delete them?

Comment: Could someone post a full example without cookies already filled in?

Comment: You can use `--cookies-file` CLI option, like so: `./phantomjs --cookies-file=./cookies.txt script.js mail@gmail.com AmazonPassword`