# PhantomJS could not find this element "driver.findElement(By.name("q")) selenium web driver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless-browser, phantomcss

I have written code using selenium web driver java to search for school and to get the first url from the search . my code is working fine without PhantomJS. But as i want to use headless browser, trying the below code to make changes.

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));` PhantomJS could not find this element "`driver.findElement(By.name("q"));` " in the below code, i tried with id too, not working out.

```
Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);

((DesiredCapabilities)caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);

((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability( PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"C:/Softwares/phantomjs-2.5.0-beta-windows/phantomjs-2.5.0.beta-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");

// Initialize browser

WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);

// And now use this to visit Google
driver.get("https://www.google.com");

// Maximize browser
driver.manage().window().maximize();

// find the text input element by its name
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

String searchSchool = "Bay High School"

// enter something to search for
element.sendKeys(searchSchool);

System.out.println("school name is "+ searchSchool);

// now submit the form
element.submit();

Thread.sleep(500);

WebElement click = driver.findElement(By.name("btnG"));

click.click();

Thread.sleep(2000);

List<WebElement> listings = driver.findElements(By.tagName("div").xpath("//cite[@class='_Rm']"));

listings.size();
```

Comment: Results of what? What is the question?

Comment: Edited the text .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413716/casperjs-doesnt-work-as-expected-on-windows-machine/41600056#41600056

Comment: i tried not working with new version too